# fontspec option "Renderer=Basic" - what does it mean?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, microtype

Since a few days I've been using the `fontspec` option `\setmainfont[Renderer=Basic] ...` in order to use the `microtype` option `tracking=true` with `LuaLaTeX`.

I have a simple question on this: why does using `Renderer=Basic` make computing my pdf sooooo much slower. It takes virtually hours now to complete on single run with `lualatexmk` -- and several (10+) minutes of high-fan-activity computing with the normal `lualatex` engine.

So, again: what does `Renderer=Basic` mean? And what is the difference to the default?

Comment: Fwiw with the latest luaotfload you can just enable letterspacing from fontspec: ``{\fontspec[LetterSpace=.125]{Iwona}foo}`` without having to request ``base`` mode. The implementation is experimental, though.

Comment: Does your `LetterSpace=.125` just always and everywhere add `.125`-space between letters? I wanted to use `tracking=true`, because it just increases the look without any further options, especially it optimises spacing of small caps. In other words is `LetterSpace=.125` equivalent to `tracking=true`?

Comment: the letterspacing callback increases kerning between glyphs by a fixed amount whereas pdftex implementation (``\letterspacefont``) that  microtype was written for increases the sidebearings of letters. Also, microtype’s ``tracking`` option includes extra functionality like handling of boundaries (outer spacing, outer kerning, etc.) that are outside the scope of font-based letterspacing.

Comment: @phg Can you add an answer?

Comment: @egreg Once it’s official, sure. Right now I’m still waiting for Robert’s input so the implementation can be finalized. I appreciate that you guys are keen on leaving nothing unanswered. On the other hand, an answer that might be invalidated by the next release isn’t worth much. At the moment letterspacing in Luaotfload is still in flux (in fact, there are two mutually incompatible implementations of it!).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Version 2.4 of Luaotfload](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/releases)
([CTAN link](http://ctan.org/pkg/luaotfload)) officially supports
letterspacing similar to Xetex.
You can enable it at font definition time
(see [the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luaotfload/luaotfload.pdf)
for details):

```
\font \mainfont = "file:Iwona-Regular.otf:letterspace=15" at 42pt
```

where the value is a percentage of the requested font size, i.e. 6.3 pt
in above example.
(Alternatively, you can specify the value directly as a factor using
the option `kernfactor`.
In order to achieve the same effect as in the example you would add
`kernfactor=0.15`.
The kern factor, though equivalent to `letterspace` in functionality,
makes more sense internally and is to a large extent consistent with
the behavior of Context’s `\setcharacterkerning` family of macros
that the letterspacing code is derived from.)
This width is inserted *as additional kern* between glyphs, with
special handling for already existing kerns, ligatures, and other
denizens of TeX’s node list.

In Fontspec terms, the feature should be directly accessible via the
`LetterSpace` key of `\fontspec`, `\set.*font` etc.

Beware, since this feature is quite new and only tested so much, there may
still be some issues with it.
Currently (January 2014) there are
[two](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/107)
[bug](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/106)
reports on the tracker that have patches in version 2.4 but require
further testing.

Also, the output is not guaranteed to be identical with Xetex or the
`\letterspacefont` primitive (or Pdftex, for that matter).
For comparison, a short test file:

```
\def \testfont {Iwona-Regular.otf}
%\def \testfont {lmroman10-regular.otf}
%\def \testfont {MinionPro_Regular.otf}
\def \testsize {20pt}

\ifdefined \directlua
  \input luaotfload.sty
  \font \mainfont                  = "file:\testfont" at \testsize
  \font \mainfontlskern            = "file:\testfont:letterspace=15" at \testsize
  \letterspacefont \mainfontlsfont = \mainfont 150
\else
  \font \mainfont         = "[\testfont]" at \testsize
  \font \mainfontlskern   = "[\testfont]:letterspace=15" at \testsize
  \def \mainfontlsfont {<unsupported!>}
\fi

\newdimen \scratchwd
\newbox   \scratchbox

\def \test #1{%
  foo
  \begingroup
    #1%
    \setbox \scratchbox \hbox {bar baz}%
    \global \scratchwd = \wd \scratchbox%
    \box \scratchbox
  \endgroup\
  bar
  (\the \scratchwd)
  \endgraf
}

\mainfont

\test \mainfontlskern %% font kerning
\test \mainfontlsfont %% increased sidebearings

\bye
```

The values for `\letterspacefont` and the `letterspace` option may
differ in subtle ways.
According to the Pdftex manual,

```
This primitive creates an instance of \Something{font} with the widths
of all glyphs increased by \Something{integer} thousandths of an em (as
set in \Something{font}).  The effect is letter spacing, but the glyphs
are actually larger (sidebearings are increased), so a single glyph will
take more space.
```

Afaics the same holds for the Luatex implementation of
`\letterspacefont`.
Since the font size and the *em* (*quad*) dimension are identical for
most fonts, the output should not differ by much.
There is, however, another more visible difference:
the `\letterspacefont` method also affects surrounding spaces whereas
`letterspace` only works between glyphs.
This behavior may change in future versions, or the *microtype* package
may add support for adapting the spacing.

---

In summation, there are three approaches to letterspacing in modern
TeX:

- **extending sidebearings** of glyphs -- this is the strategy used in Pdftex as
  well as Luatex’s `\letterspacefont`.
  The value is specified in *thousandths of an em*.
- **adding spaces** between glyphs -- according to the
  [fontspec manual](ftp://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fontspec/fontspec.pdf),
  this is the Xetex approach.
  The value is specified in *hundredths (percent) of the font size*.
- **inserting kerns** between glyphs -- this is what Context and
  Luaotfload do.
  In Context and Luatofload with the `kernfactor` option, the value
  is *a factor applied to the font size*.
  Luaotfload’s `letterspace` option (which is again used by the
  fontspec package) emulates Xetex in that it interprets the value as
  *hundredths (percent) of the font size*.

---

*Post scriptum* regarding the original question:
*fontspec*’s `Renderer` option, when used with Luaotfload, selects
one of the two available processing modes.

- `base` mode, which is the default in Context, should be “good
  enough” for most Latin-based scripts.
  Usually, though apparently not in OP’s case, it results in faster
  typesetting.
  The drawback is that `base` mode omits most Opentype features, so
  it is not an option for many scripts.
  The implementation is in
  [`font-otb.lua`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/font-otb.lua).
- `node` mode, which is the default in Luaotfload, applies Opentype
  font features during typesetting, at the cost of a minor performance
  loss.
  The features *ccmp*, *locl*, *rlig*, *liga*, *clig*, *kern*, *mark*,
  and *mkmk* are active by default for the DFLT script
  (in Luaotfload, *not* Context).
  You can look up their definition in the
  [Opentype spec](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/featurelist.htm).
  The implementation can be found in
  [`font-otn.lua`](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/font-otn.lua).

Comment: Should we use microtype or rely on the options offered by LuaTeX through luaotfload?